# get value left of max value

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-arrayformula, google-sheets-dates

I have a sheet that looks like:

```
Date         Value      Highest     Lowest
----------------------------------------------------------------
1-1-2020     23         26           20 
2-1-2020     20
3-1-2020     26
4-1-2020     22
5-1-2020     24
```

Where highest is the highest value in the value row `=MAX(B2:B999)` and lowest is the lowest value in the value row `=MIN(B2:B999)`
What I want is that below the highest value (26) I have the date of that value in this case 3 January. Also for the lowest I want to get the lowest date 2 January.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please Place under `Highest`

```
=ARRAY_CONSTRAIN(SORT(A2:B7,2,0),1,1)
```

and under `Lowest`

```
=ARRAY_CONSTRAIN(SORT(A2:B7,2,1),1,1)
```

Adjust ranges accordingly.

[image: Get highest value of dates]

Functions used:

- [`ARRAY_CONSTRAIN`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3267036)
- [`SORT`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093150)

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to accept.